# Source for Esri sample data from 911 Hot Spot Analysis

Tags: data

I was trying to replicate the [Hot Spot Analysis (Getis-Ord Gi*) from Esri](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-statistics/hot-spot-analysis.htm), but cannot find the shapefile, like the "911Count.shp", "911HotSpots.shp", etc. Can somebody tell me where I can download these shapefiles?

Comment: Might be available from https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=02b7dddf672f40c4b0129aa7420105d9 (searched for "hot spot analysis 911 dataset")

Answer (score 6):

For reference, the **911Count.shp** you're asking about is from the tool help, specifically within the Python snippets.

Eg.

```
arcpy.HotSpots_stats("911Count.shp", "ICOUNT", "911HotSpots.shp",
                     "GET_SPATIAL_WEIGHTS_FROM_FILE", "EUCLIDEAN_DISTANCE", 
                     "NONE", "#", "#", "euclidean6Neighs.swm", "NO_FDR")
```

These python snippets have been produced to show how the tool can be used. The data referenced here in this is made up / non-existent. The person who documented the tool may have the actual dataset when they wrote the snippet, but the data is not part of some master database available for download. The **911count.shp** input data could have said *purpleMonkeyDishWasher.shp* if the document author was so inclined.

The link that @smiller references in the comment (https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=02b7dddf672f40c4b0129aa7420105d9) provides similiar data (911 calls) and will work with the tool in question (Hot Spot Getis-Ord Gi*). I will point out though, that this dataset on ArcGIS.com and the 911Count from the Python snippet are merely coincidental. I don't believe the attributes found inside the arcgis.com data will match the python snippet. You'll need to update those.